# Git pre-commit hook: Prevent commits that contain executable files

Tags: bash, file-permissions, githooks

I'm trying to avoid accidentally committing binaries into my repo. I considered a hook that detects filesizes above some threshold but I think it will be more useful to fail the pre-commit hook anytime my commit changes a file with an executable permission bit.

I know how to tackle this with python/ruby/other scripting languages but ideally I can do it with just bash. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this. It lists the filenames being committed relative to `REPO_ROOT`. It passes those to `ls` with `-1` flag for one-per-line and `-F` flag that appends `*` to executables. It greps for trailing `*`. Any matching grep fails the hook.

```
cd $REPO_ROOT
STAGED_EXECUTABLES=$(git diff --diff-filter=ACMRTUXB --cached HEAD --name-only | xargs ls -1F | egrep '\*$')
EXECUTABLES_MISSING=$?
if [ $EXECUTABLES_MISSING -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "You tried to commit an executable file. Override with \`git commit --no-verify\` if required." > /dev/stderr
    exit 1
fi
```